# Как реализовать генерацию .exe в скрипте python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

Как реализовать генерацию .exe в скрипте python? Нечто похожее приходит на ум в виде Metasploit-a. Но он написан на Ruby. Именно в виде генерации exe.

Comment: Антивирусам это очень непонравится. Зачем вам это?

Comment: Вам нужна генерация исполняемого файла или компиляция? Реализуй ответ на комментарий изменением вопроса.

Comment: Не знаю как точно сказать, но нужно реализовать генерацию исходного кода с последующей компиляцией